# Poisson distribution - stuck.

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

The number of customers that arrive at the Customer’s Service counter
can be modeled with a Poisson distribution with an average of 11 per
hour. What is the probability that over the next 5 hours, there will be
exactly 3 hours where no one shows up at the counter?
All I know is that I need to compute the probability that no one shows up. But I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Is it the exact wording from a textbook?

Comment: Yup exact wording. Then I computed the probability that no one shows up in an hour, then I'm just not sure what to do next. I know how to find out the probability that no one shows up in 5 hours and 3 hours, but the exactly 3 hours over the 5 hours screws me up. What I was thinking was that for each hour, there's e^(-11) chance no one shows up, so cube that for 3 hours and I'm not sure about the remaining 2

Comment: I just wonder what must happen those another two hours

Comment: I would want the probabaility that at least 1 shows up

Comment: at least 1 in 5 hours is 1-(no one in 5 hours)

Comment: The wording of the question is not clear. My answer below is based on the assumption that each hour is counted as a distinct unit of time, eg 2-3, then 3-4 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hint....The probability of no one turning up in a given hour is, as you say, $e^{-11}=p$

Now use this as the probabililty of "success" is a Binomial distribution, where $X$ is the number of "dead" hours, so $X$ follows a Binomial distribution with parameters $5$ and $p$. Use the Binomial formula to calculate $p(X=3)$

Can you finish this?

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! I think I did something similar below if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Chubbles binomil is perhaps the best solution, but weren't you asked to do it using the poisson?

Comment: Yup, but this is okay, the poisson was for the probability of people showing up, should be fine

Comment: will it be 5C3?

Comment: Yes that's right